# Optimizing image for full page desktop with supports for responsive design

Tags: photoshop, image-size, image-optimization

Recently I have requested one of my friend to design a website for a non profit charitable organization. My friend developed using html and bootstrap. He delivered the website. I found the website is loading slow.

The website has full page image with slider in homepage. All together 3 images which can be changed by using slider. The image size, resolution may be the issue.

Please refer to the below image for the link for 
[image details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgEKx.jpg)

My friend is sick now and hospitalised. So it is not a good time for me to ask his help to modify images. I have photo shop. I need your help or share some links so that I can do it myself. Here are the area I need help.

1) As per the image, all image sizes are 1900 x 920 pixels. The resolutions are 300 and 72 dpi. Given the current Desktop/Laptop Displays resolution and cellular phone, what resolution I should save, what should be the size?

2) If I need higher resolution (as one of my image is 72 dpi) Can I simply increase the resolution to higher resolution in Photoshop? The images are natural agricultural farm.

3) How do I reduce the file size without affecting the image dimensions (width x height)? Any guidance? Tutorial links? Appreciate :)

4) I would like to replace one image s2.jpg with another image which I took using my Digital Camera. The image size is [replacement image size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho1wH.png)
What should I do in Photoshop to optimize the image?

Thank you and appreciate your inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

1). The size I'd use is 1500x1000. This is a perfect size for sliders.
2). You can easily change the dpi with this http://convert.town/image-dpi
3). To reduce the file size without changing the resolution, I'd recommend using http://www.jpegmini.com/
4). When in Photoshop with the image open, go to Image> Image size> and change the resolution to 1500x1000.